# Running NuSMV 2.6 on Windows

Tags: nusmv

I have downloaded the files from the NuSMV website, but i can't actually run the application on my system. Any leads will be appreciated.

The file contains the folders - bin,lib,share,include

Comment: *"I can't actually run the application"* is a very **vague** problem description: are you getting any error, or do you simply don't know how to use the tool? Please, show us what you tried, and describe the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to run it over command line.

Open cmd in /bin and run the command `NuSMV.exe filename.smv`

Explore the command line options and you will be able to use it however you need to